# Basically? By default?

Tags: meaning

What is different? I usually say *basically*, and say *by default* from time to time, especially when I explain something on softwares or a computer thing.
Can you give me some appropriate usage examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the world of "softwares or a computer thing" the phrase **by default** is a *strict* definition, where some property is already set to a standard or useful value until you explicity configure it. In this case

> By default, the directory will be the **current working directory**.

However **basically** is a *loose* discussion of what generally happens. It does not go deeper into the subject.

> Basically, you should consider whether the directory is accessible.

Answer (score 3):

These two expressions mean different things.

*Basically* means something *fundamental*, *essential*, or simply *inherent* to some object, process, etc.

> **Basically**, a cake is just eggs, flour, sugar, and milk -- therefore it should be a valid breakfast food.

Synonyms are: *essentially, fundamentally, inherently, mainly, primarily, centrally, principally, intrinsically*, etc.

*By default* means "unless you choose another option, this is what you get".

> **By default** the website background is white, but it can be any color you want.

Synonyms can be: *standard, stock, boilerplate, established, customary, common, usual, typical*, etc.

In some contexts *basic* can mean something similar to *by default*

> The **basic** model of this car is $37,000 but with all the options it's over $55,000.

However I prefer "the *base* model" or "the *base* version", to mean the one without any additional special features.